# Find closest values between 2 image sets in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have 2 image sets (each containing 100 images):

```
-> First set: a1, a2,..., a100 (15 images per second)
-> Second set: b1, b2,..., b100 (6 images per second)
```

So, there is a shift between the 2 image sets. I tried to match the 2 sets by generating duplicates in the second set (for the first second):

```
-> a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15
-> b1, b1, b2, b2, b3, b3, b4, b4, b5, b5, b6, b6
```

But as the number of images increases, the shift between the 2 sets increases further more. 
Does anyone know how can I find the closest values between the 2 image sets for any given number of images? Thank you.

Comment: why did u duplicate the frames ? and just how did u know how many times to duplicate it ? please make your question a bit more clear

Comment: It was a rough approximation of duplicating the frames, and I did it because I wanted the closest possible number of frames in both sets. But it's not accurate, upsampling seems not a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle this problem is to start with two time series of timeframes (A and B). Next, find the A-element that is the closest to your chosen frame in B (with `min` and `abs`). The same reasoning applies for searching B from an element in A.

```
rate1 = 15 %images per second
rate2 = 6  %images per second

%create timestamps for the two series
A = cumsum(ones(1,100) * (1/rate1));
B = cumsum(ones(1,100) * (1/rate2));

%find which of the given element in B is the closest in A 
indB = 24   % an arbitrary element of B
[M,I] = min(abs(A - B(indB)));  % I is the index of the closest A element
```

Comment: This is interesting.. thanks for sharing. What about if the frequency (number of frames per second) is not constant in both image sets?

Comment: in this problem, it doesn't matter. A and B can have any timestamps, but need to be of the same length. Generally speaking, it is not a full-proof solution, just a hint on how the problem can be seen.