# Find closest value between time vectors of different lengths in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 2 vectors, `v1` and `v2`, containing date and time data. The vectors have different lengths, with `length(v1)=15` and `length(v2)=6`. I want to obtain a new vector, `v3`, containing the closest values between `v1` and `v2`, so I can accurately match the dates and times within `v1` and `v2`. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: What will the length of the new vector be in this case?

Comment: You'll have to specify what you mean by "the closest values between". An example with real data would help with that.

Comment: is this just a generalization of you [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190243/find-closest-values-between-2-image-sets-in-matlab)?

Comment: The length of the new vector should be equal with the `length(v1)` (forgot to mention it). And yes, it's a generalization of my previous question, because I realized that my 2 data sets don't have equal lengths.

Comment: It feels like I spent time answering your previous question for nothing. Please be more specific/accurate the next time... btw you can use the `pdist2` function in the statistics toolbox to manipulate different kind of distances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the closest value in `v1` to each element of `v2`:

```
v1 = [1 3 5 3 4];
v2 = [4 5 6];                                               % // example data
[~, ind] = min(abs(bsxfun(@minus, v1(:), v2(:).')), [], 1); %'// compute all differences
                                                            % // and find index of minimizer
result = v1(ind);                                           % // build result
```

In this example,

```
result =
     4     5     5
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. How should I proceed if I want the `length(result)=length(v1)`?

Comment: In that case you want for each element of `v1` the closest element from `v2`. So just swap `v1` and `v2` in my code